# Is it possible to do a subquery like this in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gives me an error:

```
select
  case 
    when exists (select username from table_name) 
      then concat('_username_', table_name)
    else table_name
  end
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'test'
```

I basically want to return `_username_(the table name)` if the table contains a column called "user-name".

I realize there is another way to do this by selecting `information_schema.columns`, but I am set on doing it like above (if possible).

EDIT: I want my query to get all of the tables in the database test.  If the table has a column user-name, then I want it to return `_username_(followed by table name)` otherwise return table name

Comment: Rephrase your question as to what you want to be able to do from your query.

Comment: @Strawberry Why duplicate? The question asked here is different from the one asked in the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Left join to the `columns`:

```
select 
    case when column_name is null then t.table_name
        else concat('_username_', t.table_name) end
from information_schema.tables t
left join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name
    and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
    and column_name = 'user-name'
where t.table_schema = 'test'
```

The main points here are:

- All the conditions on columns must be in the join clause, so the left join is allowed. Note that "non key" conditions are OK in a join condition - this kung fu is worth remembering, because it's the only way you can make use of the left join with non-key conditions (if you put them in the where clause it becomes an inner join)
- Because column names within a table are unique, there will be either one row or no rows joined. When there is no join, the joined columns will be null - that's what's being tested in the `case`

Finally, as an aside, it would be better to name your columns without dashes, ie `username` not `user-name`, otherwise you'll have to escape it every time you use it.

Comment: I don't understand the reason of the `LEFT JOIN`. Is there a case when a column name of a table is marked as `NULL`?

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.  And I believe it would be null if "AND column_name = 'username'" columns name didn't have username

Comment: @AlbertoSolano No - the column name is never null, but if the column isn't there the *joined row* will have a null in every column. see notes added to answer

Comment: @Jason it's weird, but the same condition inside a left (outer) join and outside is quite different. Outside the column will be null if the join is missed. Inside you can specify exactly how you want to match, even if the match isn't there.

Comment: @Bohemian No rows joined? But when? When a table has no columns declared (that I think it's not possible)?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano when there are no columns **named 'username'** - note the join condition is attempting to join to the row for the column named `username` only

Comment: @Bohemian Mmm..You are using `column_name = 'username'` as matching condition, even if this could have sense in the WHERE clause and then using an inner join. Or better, use `username` in the CASE.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano No, the query wouldn't work with `column_name = 'username'` in the where clause. It's an *outer* join, so if you put the condition in the where clause, you effectively get an *inner* join. Try the query yourself on a table you've defined in mysql and experiment with putting the condition is various places. You'll discover this is the only way to do it. Understanding this approach requires a thorough understanding of how left joins work, and the implications of conditions in join conditions verses where conditions

Answer (score 1):

Without joining the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, it is not possible for you to know the columns of each table.
Try this query:

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN C.COLUMN_NAME = 'username' THEN CONCAT('_username_',C.TABLE_NAME) ELSE C.COLUMN_NAME END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test';
```

Comment: -1 This will actually give one row for every *column* in every table, but OP wants one row *per table*.

Comment: @Bohemian Where OP wrote 'one row per table'? He just wrote: 'I want my query to get all of the tables in the database test.' and then 'I want it to return _username_(followed by table name) otherwise return table name'.

Comment: It's obvious he wants one row per table, otherwise the column name would surely appear in the output

Comment: @Bohemian It's obvious in your opinion. The OP didn't ask to have only one row per table. He said explicitly ' I want my query to get all of the tables in the database test.' Then your downvote has non sense.

Comment: Ummm. I'm not sure what the confusion is here. If you want to get all the tables in the database, you don't want each table repeated for every column in that table. No, you want all the tables... once each. That's one row per table.